# gnuplot--fill the space between two functions

Tags: gnuplot

I have two functions, like:

```
f(x)=2**x
g(x)=1024
```

how can I use gnuplot to plot these two functions for x from 0 to 10 and fill the space between them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunatly gnuplot does not offer this kind of feature for functions and only for data sets. There are two ways to do this now, one of which I would recommend:

```
f(x)=2**x
g(x)=1024
xmax=10
set xrange [0:xmax]
plot '+' using 1:(f($1)):(g($1)) with filledcurves closed
```

Comment: This is nice usage of the pseudo-file '`+`'.  Nice answer.  +1

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @toxicate20 demonstrates nice usage for the pseudofile `+`.  For this particular case, that's not actually necessary since one of your functions is simply a constant:

```
set xrange [0:10]
plot 2**x w filledcurves y1=1024
```

Comment: in this situation, this answer may be right, but how about g(x)=x?

Comment: @windy -- Absolutely correct.  With this method you can't specify *arbitrary* functions -- only constants.  (you might be able to get `g(x)=x` using `with filledcurves xy=...` I'm not sure)  The other answer is definitely more general.  This one is simpler for the particular case you stated in your question.